# How to access JSON data that has assignment in the data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm using react, webpack, and express. Having trouble accessing the data. I tried axios which kinda works but not really because its not valid json so i end up just getting the entire block instead which is useless. I cant change the json. Any ideas? The JSON I have to work with looks like:

```
window.__something__ = {  
    "stuff1": {  
        "thing1": "value1",  
        "thing2": "value2"  
    },  
    "stuff2": {  
        "thing3": "value3",  
        "thing4": "thing4"  
    }  
};
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You can remove the "window.something" part and `JSON.parse()` it; What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said I can't modify the file and have to work with what I'm given. I'm just trying to access the data somehow.

Comment: So you have this as a string?
You don't have to change it, you can create a local copy (by, say, assigning the file's content to a variable) and change that.

Comment: what you see above is whats in the .json file. i tried using axios.get(the.json) and assign to a variable. all i get is the entire .json file as a string assigned to said variable. just a big paragraph isnt useful. i was thinking if there was a way to get the data but just drop the 'window.something = ' part would be perfect

Comment: Obviously you need to `parse` the data somehow, that's why I stated it's not valid JSON.

Once you have that string, it is pretty trivial to remove everything up-to and including the `=` at the beginning, and the `;` at the end.

Comment: thanks i'll give removing everything up to/including = a try. i was thinking maybe i was doing something wrong with how i was getting the data. thanks @nadavvadan

Comment: Don't forget that `;`, and once you do that, assuming the variable that stores the string is `data`, run: `var parsedData = JSON.parse(data)`. parsedData is now an object that can be easily accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the data as a string, just remove the parts you don't want a parse the rest as JSON. Assuming it always has an `=` and ends with a `;` something like this will work:

```
var str = `window.__something__ = {  
        "stuff1": {  
            "thing1": "value1",  
            "thing2": "value2"  
        },  
        "stuff2": {  
            "thing3": "value3",  
            "thing4": "thing4"  
        }  
    };`

    var cleaned = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("=")+1,str.lastIndexOf(";"));
    var json_out = JSON.parse(cleaned)
```